# Does main thread wait for child thread completion?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I have .net core on Windows and simple code. As you can see, there is no `Join()` present. So main thread doesn't wait for child, but when I run:

```
C:\...\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1>dotnet ConsoleAppTest.dll
> 4
> mission complete
> Thread complete
```

C# code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread complete");
    }).Start();

    Console.WriteLine("mission complete");
}
```

I thought main thread should run and not wait for child. Am I wrong?

When I launch

```
 Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("Thread complete");
            });
```

main thread doesn't wait

Comment: Are you running in debug or release mode? Is there any articular reason for using `Thread` directly?

Comment: release outside vs, so no side effects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`Thread.IsBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=net-6.0#remarks) documentation:

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process.

And

> By default, the following threads execute in the foreground (that is, their
> `IsBackground` property returns `false`):
>
> - The primary thread (or main application thread).
> - All threads created by calling a `Thread` class constructor.

You are creating foreground thread which prevents your process from terminating.

Also note that working with threads directly since the introduction of [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) is usually not recommended but if there is a particular reason making you to use them you can set the `IsBackground` property to `true` to allow the process to terminate:

```cs
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread complete");
});
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```